# knockout.js one viewmodel in main viewmodel(add item become undefined)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

This is code

```
<form data-bind="submit: addItem">
New item:
<input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
<button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
<p>Your items:</p>
<select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: items"> </select>
```

This is the viewmodel

```
    var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.addItem = function() {
        if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
            this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); // Adds the item. Writing to the "items" observableArray causes any associated UI to update.
            this.itemToAdd(""); // Clears the text box, because it's bound to the "itemToAdd" observable
        }
    }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
};

var masterVM = (function () {
         var self = this;      
         self.SimpleListModel= new SimpleListModel(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]);

})();
ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
```

I have to have multiple viewmodels on my page . so for starter i have created a viewmodel and put it in one master viewmodel. but addItem becomes undefined. why it is so? How can i have this approach working?

Edited

```
  <div data-bind="with: viewModel2">
       <div>
           <span data-bind="text: boardtext" />                          
       </div>           
       <a href="#" id="addVar" data-bind="click: addList ,visible: sh">Add a List</a><br /><br />
       <form method="post">           
        <div data-bind="foreach: lists" id="thumbnails">             
           <div class="thumbnail-container">
               <span data-bind="text:listname"></span><br /><br /><br /><br />
               <div id="abc">
                   <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: cardlists">
                       <li class="list-group-item">
                           <span data-bind="text: cardname"></span>
                           <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removecard">Del</a>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
                   <a href="#" data-bind="click:  $parent.showhideaddcard,visible: cardvisiblity">Add Card</a><br />
                   <div data-bind="visible: showRenderTimes">
                       <input type="text" data-bind="value: $parent.cardtext" /><br /><br /><br />
                       <input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: $parent.addcard" />
                       <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-bind="click: $parent.cancelcard" />
                   </div>
                   <div data-bind="visible: showlist">
                       <input type="text" data-bind="value: $parent.listtext" /><br /><br />
                       <input type="button" value="Save list" data-bind="click: $parent.addbuttonlist" />
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <p class="alignRight">
           <input type="submit" value="Update">
       </p>
   </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you wrapped those html inside `with: SimpleListModel`?

Comment: I just did it wrapping a with:SimpleListModel in a div around this code

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: sorry sorry it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the form using `with: ...`. Here is the sample.

```js
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
  this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
  this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
  this.addItem = function() {
    console.log("trigger AddItem");
  }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
};

var masterVM = (function () {
  var self = this;      
  self.SimpleListModel= new SimpleListModel(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]);      
})();

ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: SimpleListModel">
  <form data-bind="submit: addItem">
    New item:
    <input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
    <p>Your items:</p>
    <select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: items"></select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely a cleaner solution than mine, didn't know about the 'with' binding, great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SimpleListModel is a property of the masterVM that is bound to the page, meaning you have to prefix all your observable bindings in the HTML with SimpleListModel like so:

```
<form data-bind="submit: SimpleListModel.addItem">
New item:
<input data-bind='value: SimpleListModel.itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
<button type="submit" data-bind="enable: SimpleListModel.itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
<p>Your items:</p>
<select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: SimpleListModel.items"> </select>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/me7Lj5r1/

Comment: what about $root.removefunction? this was working previously in my code. i have not shown it here.

Comment: Pretty much, or the alternative is to use the with binding as mentioned above in a div wrapped around the html that uses the SimpleListModel property. If you didn't require the masterVM and just bound SimpleListModel to the page everything would've worked fine, but doing it the way you're now doing it is a lot more handy as it means you can have multiple view models essentially.

Comment: How can insert the viewmodel in data-bind: $root.removefunction

Comment: is $root.removefunction a part of the masterVM or a part of the SimpleListModel?

Comment: SimpleListModel

Comment: Hmmm well that is strange, but I can't really give an accurate answer without seeing the code. But what's especially strange about that is $root.removefunction would have looked for the removefunction in the masterVM, at the same level that SimpleListModel is.

Comment: I have  edit . you can spot $root.removecard very easily in that viewmodel.  can you spot any mistake? i do have a with in the code

Comment: I've seen, but that HTML is wrapped in a 'with: viewModel2' binding similar to M. Ihsan's solution.

Comment: yes but the $root.removecard didn't work. so that's why your solution rings bell in my head

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think I get you, $root will return to the root of the page binding, in this case masterVM (so it's trying to bind to masterVM.removecard), if removecard is a function within viewModel2 then the best thing you can do that I can think of is $root.viewModel2.removecard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140067/discussion-between-maztt-and-dibsyjr).